# Convergence of product of uniform r.v?!

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

**Say we have n iid RV distributed uniformly across (0,2). Let $X_n = U_1U_2U_3\cdots U_n$. In which of the senses  (almost surely, in probability, mean square, distribution)  does $X_n$ converge?**

---

I know I have to follow the definition for each of the types of convergence and see if $X_n$ meets them. But what do I substitute for $X_n$ and $X$ in the definitions? For example, for convergence in probability, $P(|X_n - X|>\epsilon) = 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

What would I use for $X_n$? For $X$, I typically use the values/distributions I expect the sequence to converge to, but I have no clue what that would be in this case.

Comment: C'mon someone plz help me answer this?

Answer (score 2):

You can see that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale because $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)) = X_n\mathbb{E}(U_{n+1}) = X_n$ and this martingale is positive then converge a.e. ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems)) to a random variable $X_\infty$ (hence in probability too). Using that $\mathbb{E}(U_n^2) = \frac{4}{3}$, you can demonstrate that $X_n$ doesn't converge in $L^2$.

Comment: Ok ! I missed the 1/2 part.

Comment: It's a good answers - maybe you can add this link to the theorem you are using to be more precise : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems